# Cronjob in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to run cronjob in ubuntu 13.04. When place my crontest.php file at the root 
ie /var/www/crontest.php

then it is working fine. But as soon as i place it in a subdirectory ie

/var/www/test/cron/crontest.php

its not working anymore.

My crontab command is as follows:

```
22 6 * * * /usr/bin/php   /var/www/crontest.php
```

for the first case and

```
22 6 * * * /usr/bin/php   /var/www/test/cron/crontest.php
```

for the second case.

Please help.

Comment: what do you mean is not working?

Comment: crontest.php file contains a code to send an email. In the second case the file isn't getting executed as m not receiving any email.

Comment: does the above script run manually without cronjob?

Comment: ya its working fine without cronjob. Am I missing any permission settings?? I have given full permissions to all the folders and files. Still don't know where am i wrong?